# How orginise federative repository in DDD way?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I want to create general list of all type of feedbacks - FeedbackRepository 
I have already some repositories:

- FeedbackFromPhoneRepository (store in db)
- FeedbackFromMailRepository (store in otrs)
- FeedbackFromSiteRepository (store somewhere else)

My first idea was to merge these repositories in FeedbackRepository.
But i find out that it's no good way when one repository have access to other. 
How is the right way to organise this multiple repository in DDD practice?

Comment: Why do you store the feedback in different places?

Comment: What are your entities? Is feedback read only or can you C/U/D feedback?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this and one would probably need more information about the rest of your design. As the repository is an abstraction over your store for information you could have a FeedbackService that provides encapsulation over the repositories e.g

```
  IFeedbackService
  {
       IList<FeedBack> GetFeedBackFor(SomeFeedBackIdentifier id)
  }
```

Your implementation could have the required repos (injected of course) and handle reading from each one and collating the responses.

Whilst the Repository concept came from the DDD world there is nothing about this that wouldn't carry over to any approach to software. Encapsulation is an important construct (in OO at least anyway) and that's what you could do here - encapsulate the need to read from many places and give the consumer to the service a nice way to do this.

Looking at this form a DDD point of view you might want to consider if you have got your bounded context correct for feedback but that is another story.